# Change page title using javascript inside a PHP 'if'

Tags: javascript, php, title

Here is the situation :
I'm trying to get a page's title and content to change when clicking on a menu link without reloading the whole document.
So far, changing the content works like a charm. But I have some issues with changing the title.

Here is the code so I'm understandable when I explain it :

```
if (isset($_GET['rq'])) {
    $rq = $_GET['rq'];
    foreach($lesMenus as $menuName=>$menuContent){
        foreach($menuContent as $name=>$link){
            $linkW = substr($link, 0, strpos($link, '.'));
            if($linkW == $rq){
                $newTitle = $name;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isset($newTitle)){
        $title = $newTitle;
        echo("<script type=\"text/javascript\">
             document.title =".$newTitle.";
             </script>");
    }
    $mainContent='You have asked for :'.$rq;
    echo $mainContent;
}
else{
    include('INC/layout.html.inc.php');
}
```

What happens is : When a menu-link is clicked, a function is called and after some work does this : `xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php?rq=" + rq , true);`

What you have here is basically the groundwork of that `index.php` page.

The double `foreach` loop skims the `$lesMenus` array for `rq`'s counterpart.

Now the problem is that the script inside the `if (isset($newTitle))` does not play. Everything else does (I've tried `echo $newTitle;` and it does it, the page's content changes according to what is asked, but the script does not play. Even a simple Hello world inside that script does not happen.

I've searched stackOverflow and the web for a way to play javaScript inside PHP and this is what seemed to work for other people, but in my case it doesn't.

Any pointers ? :)

Thanks for reading me,

Chris (IT Student)

Comment: JS is rendered on page load...so I don't think adding it to the script like that will trigger it. try calling it in a anonymous function call or settimeout function

Comment: @NishanthMatha So rather than changing the title in the index.php page, changing it in the function that is called upon clicking on a menu link ? I'll try that

Comment: Definitely sure it's the javascript not running? As far as I can tell, if `$newTitle` is `"Home"`, the javascript inserted would be `document.title = Home;` which would look for the `Home` variable rather than set `document.title` to the string `"Home"`

Comment: @ThorbjørnKappelHansen Affirmative. I tried `document.title="test"` along with the \ to keep the `"` in the script, I tried `alert ('test');`, I tried to change the background color, I tried a bunch of simple javascript actions just to see if they would run, but no luck there.

Comment: @BatteMan Ah okay, then I'm not sure

Comment: as @ThorbjørnKappelHansen has mentioned, you have a syntax error in this line `document.title =".$newTitle.";`. you can fix it by adding single quotes before and after the `php variable` and change it to this: `document.title ='".$newTitle."';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding the script to the DOM won't cause it to execute.  So you need to call it somehow, maybe by wrapping it in a function and calling it by name.

However, if you are going to do that, you may as well echo only the newTitle and update it after you do the http request:

JS:

```
<!-- Assuming you have something like this -->
<script>
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
           var responseText = xhttp.responseText;
           document.title = responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "index.php?rq=" + rq , true);
    xhttp.send();

</script>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($newTitle)){
    echo($newTitle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that kinda helped. I changed my way of thinking and used the `.text` attribute of the link I was clicking, and used `document.title` in the function attributed to the menu links at load (your `xhttp.onreadystatechange` tipped me in the right direction as I was using it already to load the content)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

there is diffrent way to change page title.
simply you can change it by passing data to a javacsript variable like this:

```
<script>
var jTitle=<?= $phpContainnewTitle; ?>
</script>
```

and after it change it as below with javascript:

```
  document.title = jTitle;
```

**BUT** it cause reduce SEO rank. Title is important tag in SEO. 
pay attention to this .

Answer (score 0):

You can do your condition check in PHP, and store the title in `$newTitle` and maybe create another boolean `$needToChangeTitle`.

instead of using PHP to echo the script tag. Just put the script tag in as HTML and do another condition check.

```
var needToChangeTitle = "<?php echo $needToChangeTitle ?>";
var newTitle = "<?php echo $newTitle ?>";
if (needToChangeTitle === "true") {
  document.title = newTitle;
}
```